# How to insert new data points into CartoDB map?

Tags: javascript, carto, geojson

I'm using NASA api data to populate my database in CartoDB's website to load places where meteorites have fallen. 
In JavaScript I'm currently creating a specific collection of meteorites I want to appear on the map, and these will change based on how users interact with the map. The more they click, new ones should appear.

The issue I'm facing currently is that I cannot find out how to call for this specific collection of meteorites to appear on the map. Since it changes based on several factors, I'm thinking that making SQL queries won't work and instead I would want to create a new viz.json file.

I'm confused on where does the data go into cartodb.createviz(. Looking at examples such as [visjson spec](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/doc/vizjson_format.md) there's no hints of where exactly the data goes.

Comment: Are you using the web service user interface to create the map or using the API to do visualization yourself?

Comment: I'm using the API to do the visualization.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [CartoDB SQL API](https://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api/) with [CartoDB.js](https://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js/) to call the data that you want to display depending on where the user click. In [this section](https://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js/sql/) of the CartoDB documentation you can find more information about using theCartoDB SQL API within CartoDB.js.

In [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/8aa16503402bd37fc781) you can find how a buffer is created everytime that a user clicks on the map and the points are pinpointed on the map where the buffer intersects with them.

On the other hand, the createViz method it calls all the elements of the map using the viz.json. I would recommend creating the map using the CartoDB.js [createLayer()](https://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js/api-methods/#cartodbcreatelayermap-layersource--options--callback) method to call the data. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/a3332612907c0757ef6a) you can find an example to create a map using the createLayer method.

You would need to create a table in your CartoDB account to store the collection of meteorites and make them appear on the map using the SQL API or CartoDB.js.